# header meta tag lost in icefaces 4.1

Tags: meta-tags, websphere-8, icefaces

in my page page.xhtml i have a header like this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
   xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></meta>
```

but what i get after deployement is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="/test/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css.jsf?ln=icefaces.ace&amp;v=4_1_0_160615"
```

i'm using icefaces 4.1.0 EE Version, application deployed under a websphere 8.0.0.5.

Comment: ticket is opened http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/IPCK-554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is most probaly caused by the classloading of Websphere portal specific libraries. When they are classloaded our code will assume that the application runs in a portal environemnt. That is when the elements contained by the head are removed (see ICE-11042 why we have this behaviour).

I would recommend to the customer to verify what libraries are loaded by Websphere. Not loading the portal specific libraries should fix this issue.